# Only one list element goes first On page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to make that one li element will be first one, as user in the next page click  (www.url.com/demo/#collapse1) - should be the first one or (www.url.com/demo/#collapse5) - shoul be the first one? and the other elements will stay in their places, when you are in same page. www.url.com/demo

```js
$('li').click(function() {
  $(this).prependTo($(this).parent());
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 0;
  text-indent: 10px;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  background: #eee;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#one">01</a></li>
  <li><a href="#two">02</a></li>
  <li><a href="#three">03</a></li>
  <li><a href="#four">04</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">05</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you want to achieve, can you explain it a little bit more?

Comment: For example : You was in facebook and saw www.url.com/#something link.
You clicked on it. That element was last on page. But he goes first because you clicked on that link, but others elements stay in their places.

Comment: So in your example, if I click on '3' it goes up (order is now `3 - 1 - 2 - 4 - 5`) and then if you click on 4 the order is (`4 - 3 - 1 - 2 - 5`) but you actually want: `(4 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 5)`?

Comment: Yes, and i need it only on page load, than user click on link with hashtag or something like that.

Comment: So if the user goes to "yoururl/#two" then the order is: 2 - 1 - 3 - 4 - 5 right? Then the user clicks on 3, the url is: yoururl/#three and the order is: 3 - 1 - 2 - 4 - 5?

Comment: That is exactly what I need .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're looking for a way to swap between the first element and the clicked on element.  Here's a way to accomplish that by using `.detach`.  First, we grab the `.siblings` and then we grab the first element from the list via `.eq`.  From there we detach it (or remove it from the HTML but keep it stored as a variable.  Next we prepend our clicked on element to the parent, detaching that one too only after assigning `first` has been appended to after our current element.  Basically, swapping the two elements.

```js
$('li').click(function() {
  first = $(this).siblings().eq(0).detach()
  $(this).parent().prepend($(this).after(first).detach());
});

if (window.location.hash != "") {
 $('li').eq(Number(window.location.hash.slice(1))-1).click();
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 0;
  text-indent: 10px;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  background: #eee;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#1">01</a></li>
  <li><a href="#2">02</a></li>
  <li><a href="#3">03</a></li>
  <li><a href="#4">04</a></li>
  <li><a href="#5">05</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Awesome. Could you please explain your logic

Comment: @TamilSelvanC I updated my answer with the logic explained.

Comment: But how can i do it with links ? For exmaple :  if the user goes to "url/#two" then the order is: 2 - 1 - 3 - 4 - 5 , then the user clicks on 3, the url is: url/#three and the order is: 3 - 1 - 2 - 4 - 5.

Comment: @Mantas  Updated the example go ahead and give it a go.  If you could mark as solution, it'd help a lot.